# How to maintain a Mac protected on the Internet when any sharing is on?

Tags: network, security, firewall, file-sharing

### Mac with Internet door closed

When a Mac is connected to the Internet
but no sharing is activated it is correctly protected on the Internet side.

A protection situation one can check with a tool like `nmap`:

```
#   far-away-Mac:/Users/bob        % nmap -Pn my-home-Mac
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-08-19 19:18 CEST
Nmap scan report for my-home-Mac (12.23.34.45)
Host is up (0.0051s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on my-home-Mac (12.23.34.45) are closed (500) or filtered (500)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.04 seconds
#   far-away-Mac:/Users/bob        %
```

I would schematize this situation as: [image: Mac with Internet door closed]

### Mac with Internet door open

On the other hand, as soon as some sharing services are activated,
ex: `System Preferences… > Sharing > File Sharing`,
many access are opened on all interfaces and what is most annoying on the Internet side.
A much less secure situation one can check once more with `nmap`:

```
#   far-away-Mac:/Users/bob        % nmap -Pn my-home-Mac
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-08-19 19:42 CEST
Nmap scan report for my-home-Mac (12.23.34.45)
Host is up (0.0016s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
80/tcp   filtered http
88/tcp   open     kerberos-sec
443/tcp  filtered https
445/tcp  open     microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open     ipp
3283/tcp filtered netassistant
5900/tcp open     vnc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.72 seconds
#   far-away-Mac:/Users/bob        %
```

I would schematize this situation as: [image: Mac with Internet door open]

### Mac sharing with Internet door closed

How to use sharing but only for my "Home" network and not for the rest of the Internet
so as to stay in the initial situation with an Internet door **closed**?

I guess this can be achieved with packet filter and I am working to build a complete
solution, but I would like to know if anyone has a better idea or suggestion?

Comment: So, do you have a firewall on your network?  And when you say "sharing" or on your Home network do you mean you want  to file share, remote manage, or remote login while on the same network or where one computer is on the Internet and the other is at home - in your words, from behind the closed door?

Comment: As everyone I have a firewall managed by my ISP, accessible by my ISP and configured as tight as possible by myself. It is based on a solid OS but I can't trust it. This is the reason I didn't put it in my scheme to wasting time on this point of failure (I don't want to panic everyone about the insecurity of mass market routers). I project to buy and build another firewall of my own.

Comment: I have another level of firewall on my Mac which is distributing the Wi-Fi network inside my home. And this is the part of my network on which I tried to focus. •••• I want to secure this Mac exactly as it is when no sharing is activated : 0 open port on the external side.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have specifically without using the "open/closed door" conceptualizations?  As such, it's impossible to  tell if you have an ISP provided modem or bona fide firewall, if you're using a secondary firewall and what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: [bis] As everyone I have a firewall managed by my ISP, accessible by my ISP and configured as tight as possible by myself. It is based on a solid OS but I can't trust it. This is the reason I didn't put it in my scheme to avoid wasting time on this point of failure. This is out of the scope of my question. I am focusing on securing a MacOS.